# Function declaration without arguments

Tags: sml

How do I declare a function in the signature for that doesn't take arguments?

I've only seen function signatures with arguments like this: `leq:item*item->bool`
and I am looking to create a signature for function like this:

```
initBTree = E   (* where empty is of type tree *)
```

this doesn't work: `val initBTree:->tree`

Comment: You might wan't to elaborate a bit on you question. It doesn't really make any sense. Possibly add some real code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a function that takes unit as its parameter, like this:

```
fun initBTree () = E
```

And call it like this:

```
initBTree ()
```

It has type

```
fn : unit -> tree
```

If `E` has type `tree`.

That's kinda pointless, though. You might as well just say `E`, or if you really want it to be called initBTree:

```
val initBTree = E
```

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know all functions in SML takes exactly one argument. Thus creating a function that takes no arguments is impossible, as such a "thing" would actually just be a value.

Your code

```
val initBTree : -> tree
```

makes absolutely no sense. If you say that you have a value constructor `E` which is the empty tree, why would you wan't to create an init function that doesn't initialise a tree with any thing? In that case `initBTree` would be a synonym for `E` and you could do

```
val initBTree = E
```

However this would still be pointless.